# Prolog Concept - Replace an Atom Using Recursion

Tags: prolog, traversal, functor

I am having trouble grasping the concept of 'tree' traversal in Prolog.

Given an input list, following code replaces the atom hi to bye if present in leaves (ignore functors). I put comments % next to portions that confuse me:

```
replace([],[]).

replace([H | T], [H1 | T1]):-
    (  H == hi -> H1 = bye;  
       replace(H, H1)  % P1: What exactly does replace (H,H1) do? I know that
                       %     is saying if H = hi then H1 = bye; else ..
    ),
replace(T, T1).        

% The rule below is called in the replace(H,H1) above as well as the replace(T,T1). 
% I am unsure as to what exactly this does.

replace(L, R):-
    L =.. [F1 | Args1],
    replace(Args1, Args2),
    R =.. [F1 | Args2].
```

The code above outputs:

```
?- replace(put(hi,table,aside(hi(dont,replace),hi)),X).
X = put(bye, table, aside(hi(dont, replace), bye))
```

I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have defined only one rule here -- if you run the query `listing(replace/2)` you'll see that there are 3 clauses. Is that what you intended?

Comment: If you enter ";" after the answer to your query `replace(put(hi,table,aside(hi(dont,replace),hi)),X)`, you'll get another answer; in fact, you'll get an infinite number of answers on backtracking.

Comment: I have been trying to explain the Prolog Clause in [this page](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/prolog_clause_explainer.md) (an updated page of something I tried to do for the work team once ... that was not a success, people left the lecture - not better than when I was doing the undergraduate exercise courses ) ... don't know whether this makes things clearer or more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The second clause of replace/2 applies the operator [=..](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) (called for historical reasons *univ*) to get a different representation of a term, as list `[Functor|Arguments]`, then attempts the replacement of such *Arguments*, and at last reassembles the term, always by means of univ.

If you want to replace the functor as well, just simplify the clause:

```erlang
replace(L, R):-
    L =.. In,
    replace(In, Out),
    R =.. Out.
```

Since Prolog has a *relational* data model, sometimes input/output distinction doesn't help, and anyway it's just a naming convention. What is important it's the *instantiation* pattern of the arguments. Builtin predicates (univ it's an example) usually attempt to offer the most flexible model, that is, they can work *backwards*, but this feature not always is feasible.

For this snippet, In/Out clearly convey the meaning...

Comment: Oh, I noticed the markdown markup "```erlang" for [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Good idea ... Prolog is such an orphan. But apparently SO uses [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) ... which has a [Logtalk](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-logtalk.js) mode!

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: good catch. Logtalk should fit much better than Erlang, that misses multiline comments.